# Turn redis keys into javascript object?

Tags: javascript, json, string, redis

I want to grab all the users from redis and pass it into my template.

What I am getting returned is an array like `['users:nick','users:mike']`

I dont want to have to regex it, I would like to take the usernames and store it inside an array of objects `[{username: 'nick'}]`

```
redisSessionClient.keys("users:*", function(err, users) {
  if(err) {
    console.log(err);
    return;
  }

  for (i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
    console.log(users[i])
  }

  res.render('chat', req.user);
});
```

I think I am a little confused with the redis way of doing things and syntax, so I am open for any suggestions.

Comment: If you're using `KEYS` (or, in your case `redisSessionClient.keys`) in your application code, be prepared for a world of pain.

Comment: Ok good to know... I am not actually using it, was just for a test user login system I was playing around with.

Comment: @MichaelJosephAubry Check my newly added answer. The one you've selected is very very wrong. As Itama has said, you mustn't use `keys` command on application code!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redis uses strings as keys, so you just have to parse it:

```
redisSessionClient.keys('users:*', function(err, users) {
  var newArray = users.map(function(user) {
    return {
      username: user.split(':')[1]
    };
  });

  // newArray is what you wanted
});
```

**Edit:** seeing as this answer was accepted, I'll echo everyone's concerns about why using `keys` is inappropriate in production.

To query all the keys in Redis takes O(n) time, where n is the total number of keys you have stored. So if you have 1 million keys but only 200k of those keys have the `users:` prefix, you've essentially wasted 800k operations by using `keys` to get a list of all your usernames. This is an expensive operation that could have major performance impacts on your production application.

Matias' answer is a good example of how to use these commands if you have a set of all your usernames.

Comment: This answer is wrong. `keys` mustn't be used in application code.

Comment: Agreed, recommending keys in production is the wrong way to do this.

Comment: Doesn't make the answer any less correct, especially considering he was already using `keys` in the example. Also, a comment from OP above states that this was from a non-production test. In fact, I use `keys` all the time when scripting/running isolated queries on Redis.

Comment: OP and other readers visit SO because they want to learn technologies. I don't find a strong argument your point. In fact the issue with this command isn't it's complexity but it's blocking nature.

Comment: I would completely drop this answer because it provides our enforces a very wrong development pattern. The whole command is meant to be used in Redis CLI for maintenance purposes...

Comment: As @MatíasFidemraizer says it isn't the complexity or "operations", it is the fact that it all *block the entire server for the duration of the command*. You don't even need a set as you can use the `SCAN` command which will not block the entire server for the time it takes to iterate over the entire keyspace. The answer *is* actually incorrect as it goes against the documentation of Redis itself in it's usage and avoid the correct way to do it.

Comment: @TheRealBill It seems like this poster prioritizes fame over correctness

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer not sure what "fame" you are referring to ... I am unable to delete my post as it was already accepted. Seeing how important it is to you that my answer be dropped, what do you suggest I do?

Comment: You could remove the keys recommendation and answer instead with how to do it using SCAN, perhaps with a footnote that it originally was answered with keys but that you've changed it to avoid said worst practice.

Answer (score 2):

What you need is storing all nicknames in a set and just call `smembers`or `sscan` on the set key.

Whenever you register a new user, you'll need to both add your users wherever you want and also add the nickname *as is* to a set called, for example, `users:names`.

That is, if you call `smembers` or `sscan` using the following code, you'll get things done right:

```
redisSessionClient.smembers('users:names', function(err, userNames) {
  var newArray = userNames.map(function(userName) {
    return {
      username: userName
    };
  });
});
```

At the end of the day, you need to change your mind when working with Redis: if you need to get some property values of some entity, then you'll need to store these values separately and get them. It's like working with raw indexes.

Anyway, take a look at [`scan`-based commands](http://redis.io/commands/scan) to go further and even get a better approach. In simple cases and not that big databases, `smembers` should be fine.

Comment: Thanks for this, I am enjoying learning Redis and this project was just me playing around with it. I am using MongoDB for the real thing, but I want to use both effectively!